# Enqueue Script in WordPress

Tags: wp-enqueue-script

How to enqueue script in WordPress ?

When I am using below code script enqueue properly.

```php
wp_enqueue_script( 'adc-handlebars', get_template_directory_uri() . '/vendors/handlebars/handlebars.min.js', array(), '1.2.1', false );
```

But when I am using below code script is not enqueue.

```php
wp_enqueue_script('adc-order-information', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/order_information.js', array(), '2.10.0', true);
```

Comment: Do you have any browser console errors?

Comment: Thanks @Taruc. No, there is no error in browser console. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your first snippet sets `$in_footer` to false so the the script will be added to the `<head />` of your document.

The second snippet sets `$in_footer` to true and so it will be added at the bottom of your document (usually just before `</body>`, but it depends on where `wp_footer()` is called in your theme).

Read more about [`wp_enqueue_script()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/)

Comment: Thanks @TheDeadMedic. But I couldn't find the script `adc-order-information` in Source code. I can find the first one. What will be the cause ? Thanks.

Comment: @Foysal Are you calling both snippets in the same place? Is there a chance that `adc-order-information` is already registered elsewhere?

Comment: Thanks @TheDeadMedic. Yes, I am calling both snippets in the same place. I searched the whole code. There is no chance that `adc-order-information` is already registered elsewhere. Even I searched in Source code there is no `adc-order-information`.

Comment: @Foysal What happens if you change the `$in_footer` argument from `true` to `false`?

Comment: Thanks @TheDeadMedic. Now I am trying `wp_enqueue_script( 'adc-handlebars', get_template_directory_uri() . '/vendors/handlebars/handlebars.min.js', array(), '1.2.1', false );
    
    wp_enqueue_script( 'adc-handlebars1', get_template_directory_uri() . '/vendors/handlebars/handlebars1.min.js', array(), '1.2.1', false );`. Here is also second one is not working. Thanks.

Comment: @Foysal I'm sorry, I don't know what else to suggest